# New tag for Amazon Alexa voice integration

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation

Should there be a tag created for questions about integrating Alexa skills with various web apps (Google Docs, calendars, etc.)? The current [`alexa`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alexa) tag refers to the [Alexa.com](https://www.alexa.com/) marketing site (also owned by Amazon) rather than the Alexa voice SDK or related skills.

Here are some current questions that could use this tag:

- [Google Docs - Need to update every entry with today's date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114364/google-docs-need-to-update-every-entry-with-todays-date)
- [Get Alexa to send the current Spotify song to a list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108933/get-alexa-to-send-the-current-spotify-song-to-a-list)
- [Make Office 365 Calendar Events Accessible in Alexa, or iCal via Google Calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102529/make-office-365-calendar-events-accessible-in-alexa-or-ical-via-google-calendar/102618#102618)

Just brainstorming here, but it could be `alexa-sdk`, `alexa-skill`, `alexa-voice-integration` -- or something else entirely.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but we need to make sure the scope is only for integration with web apps. Personally, I like [tag:alexa-skill].

Comment: @ale I agree. To your point, `alexa-skill` would be better than the other two because it focuses on the end user aspect of it rather than the developer aspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've gone ahead and created [alexa-skill](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alexa-skill) and added an excerpt. It could probably use a full description.